# “Analysis is run daily.” is it correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, active-vs-passive

The following sentence is in an email from Google: “Analysis is run daily.”

Please let me understand, why it isn’t “analysis runs daily” or “analysis does run daily” or “analysis is running daily”? Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Google sends emails to you? Of course, The grass is cut daily.

Answer (score 2):

This is the passive voice.  It is equivalent to

> (Somebody) runs analysis daily.

The purpose of the passive voice is to indicate that there is a person who actively runs the analysis: it doesn't run itself.  But the speaker doesn't know, and it doesn't matter who that person is.

We could say "Analysis runs daily". That would suggest a fully automatic process that is not done by a person, but "just happens".

Comment: Additionally, the analysis could be run by a computer. But as James says, it's the "agency", whether person or device, that conducts this running that requires the passive voice here.